# Шаблонная строка в react компоненте viewBox=`0 0 ${width} ${height}` не работает

Tags: javascript, reactjs, svg

```js
const About = ({width = '24', height = '24'}) => (
    <svg width={width} height={height} viewBox=`0 0 ${width} ${height}` fill="none">
  <path fillRule="evenodd" clipRule="evenodd"
        d="M12 2C6.48 2 2 6.48 2 12C2 17.52 6.48 22 12 22C17.52 22 22 17.52 22 12C22 6.48 17.52 2 12 2ZM11 17V15H13V17H11ZM11 7V13H13V7H11Z"
        fill="#2F80ED"/>;
</svg>
);

JSX value should be either an expression or a quoted JSX text 


Это работает

<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44426933/template-string-of-es6-in-attribute-of-react-component

Comment: Спасибо помогло